# Unable to use recorded clip as sound in local notification

Tags: swift, avaudiorecorder, localnotification

In my app, the user could record audio, up to 25 seconds.

I saved the audio in document directory as "1.m4a", and whenever the user records again, it replaces the original file in "1.m4a".

I wanted to play "1.m4a" as the sound for my local notification. I found sources that said it was not possible, but also some sources said it was possible it is stored in the Library/Sounds directory. What does this mean? Could anyone teach me how I could do that please!

My function to record audio works well and I have a button that can play the recorded audio when clicked.

Record audio:

```
@IBAction func recordAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    counter = 0
    startCounter()

    if (audioRecorder == nil) {
        audioReadyLabel.isHidden = true
        counterLabelOutlet.isHidden = false
        numberOfRecords = 1
        let fileName = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(numberOfRecords).m4a")

        let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVSampleRateKey: 12000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileName, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record()
            stopOutlet.isHidden = false
            stopLabelOutlet.isHidden = false
            recordOutlet.isHidden = true
            recordLabelOutlet.isHidden = true
        }
        catch {
            displayAlert(title: "Oops", message: "Recording failed")
        }
    }
    else {
        stopOutlet.isHidden = true
        stopLabelOutlet.isHidden = true
        audioRecorder.stop()
        //what does the below mean ***
        audioRecorder = nil
        counterTimer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Play audio:

```
func playPeptalk() {
    let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(numberOfRecords).m4a")

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch {

    }
}
```

Local notification:

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Rise & Shine"
    content.subtitle = "Let's start the day!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName("1.m4a"))
```

Answer (score 0):

From  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound)

> Audio files must already be on the user’s device before they can be played. If you use a predefined set of sounds for your notifications, include the audio files in your app’s bundle. For all other sounds, place a copy of the audio file in the **Library/Sounds** folder of your app’s container directory. The UNNotificationSound object looks only in those two locations

Comment: How do I place a copy of the audio file in the Library/Sounds folder of my app’s container directory?